# Codeigniter + Lampstack - Unable to connect to your database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have this on my localhost and it works perfectly fine.

but when i put it on a server i configured the database settings correctly

here is my config/database.php

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '111.111.1.111', //sample host
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'mydatabase',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'port'     => '1234',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => FALSE
);
```

but all i got was the error

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: third_party/MX/Base.php

Line Number: 55
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I suppose you are using the correct username and password right? Instead of root?

Comment: you should NEVER be using the root db account for anything other than administration tasks. that's a major security problem. and have you tried c connecting to the db using those settings manually via the mysql commandline interface?

Comment: yes. i think i am using the correct one @CaptainRed

Comment: @MarcB we have other php programs that doesnt use code igniter but it works.

Comment: are you using the correct host i thing you need to change it in localhost and try again

Comment: @Yaseen my database engineer said he gave me all the right creds. and he said its working on other php programs that we have. but the difference is,its not codeigniter made